# AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'stats'

Tags: python, statsmodels, attributeerror

I'm running statsmodels 0.13.2 on macOS Monterey v 12.4 with M1 chip.

I'm trying to do a z-test with `statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest`

Per [the website](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest.html) this really seems like the correct syntax.

However, when I try to do this, I get the error message

"AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'stats'"

I'm beyond confused. Has anyone ever had this issue before or know wha is going on??

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/api-structure.html you need to import the module or the api modules. Nothing is imported by default, so we have an option to only selectively import modules instead of importing everything each time.

Comment: Try `from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest`